# Software to model car paint designs

Tags: windows, modeling, 3d

I am looking for a software that allows me to model paint designs that I can apply to a car. My objective is to play with the paint designs that I can apply to a car before going to a body shop and asking them what I want to do on my car. Here are the requirements:

- Free (if there are no free versions, paid versions are acceptable).
- For Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quite a steep learning curve and probably overkill but you could use [Blender 3D](http://www.blender.org/) to first model your car, (there may already be a model out there that someone else has done and released into the public domain), then apply various colour schemes to the model.

Minus Points:

- Large
- You have to learn to use it and to 3D model
- You may well get hooked

Plus points:

- Free
- Cross platform including Windows
- Full 3D
- Can produce full photo quality renders/videos and animations
- Lots of books/web sites/help & tutorials, e.g. [modelling sports car in cycles](http://cgcookie.com/blender/cgc-courses/rendering-a-sports-car-in-blender-cycles/).
- You will learn to 3D model
- You will probably get hooked.

Example from the above tutorial:[image: porche]